# Win+Tab opens Window Switching Menu instead of Alt+Tab

Tags: windows, alt-tab

I'm experiencing a weird issue on Windows, suddenly  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't open the window switching menu but <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does and when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it opens the windows search. I would appreciate if anybody could help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: What version of Windows are you on, and are you subscribed to an insider version as well? For all we know, Microsoft is testing a new feature.

Comment: @LPChip Im using Windows 10 21H2 and I'm not subscribed to windows insider

Comment: There could be a key stuck. Have you tried to reboot?

Comment: Tried this on Windows 10 / 11 and no issue here.  Try running DISM / SFC as the initial repair step ......  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Does your keyboard have a switch to change from ``Windows(/Android)`` to  ``Mac(/IOS)`` layout?  If so, check that the switch is on ``Windows``.  Example: [Keychron K2 Switch Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4hHN.png).  If that is the issue I'll post as answer.